# How to make "Yes"/"No" code shorter?

Tags: jquery

I have these dynamic checkboxes each with ID + number +1. Could anyone tell me how to make this code shorter? Probably nothing difficult, but I just started with jquery and javascript, so it's a bit complicated for me :(

```
    if(!$('#g:checked').length){
        $("#h").val("No");
} else {
        $("#h").val("Yes");
}
if(!$('#g2:checked').length){
        $("#h2").val("No");
} else {
        $("#h2").val("Yes");
}
if(!$('#g3:checked').length){
        $("#h3").val("No");
} else {
        $("#h3").val("Yes");
}
if(!$('#g4:checked').length){
        $("#h4").val("No");
} else {
        $("#h4").val("Yes");
}
if(!$('#g5:checked').length){
        $("#h5").val("No");
} else {
        $("#h5").val("Yes");
}
if(!$('#g6:checked').length){
        $("#h6").val("No");
} else {
        $("#h6").val("Yes");
}
if(!$('#g7:checked').length){
        $("#h7").val("No");
} else {
        $("#h7").val("Yes");
}
if(!$('#g8:checked').length){
        $("#h8").val("No");
} else {
        $("#h8").val("Yes");
}
if(!$('#g9:checked').length){
        $("#h9").val("No");
} else {
        $("#h9").val("Yes");
}
if(!$('#g10:checked').length){
        $("#h10").val("No");
} else {
        $("#h10").val("Yes");
}
```

Comment: Can you add a class to all of these elements?

Comment: post your html will help peoples to answer your question

Comment: for future reference, [we've got a site for this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a simple loop, eg.

```
var n;
for(n=1; n<10; n++) {
    $('#h'+n).val( $('#g'+n).is(':checked') ? 'Yes' : 'No' );
}
```

And the tertiary operator makes the logic a little more compact as well.
You should rename your 'h' and 'g' element ids to 'h1' and 'g1' for consistency.

Comment: Wow, that was really fast! Thank you guys! I will stick with suggestion by a'r. Worked for me :)

Answer (score 10):

The best thing to do here is to adjust the markup so that it's friendlier to the needs of your code.  Even if you don't do that, however, you can do something like this:

```
$('input:checkbox').each(function() {
  var cb = this;
  $('#h' + cb.id.replace(/^g/, '')).val(cb.checked ? 'Yes' : 'No');
});
```

Personally I dislike doing gymnastics with "id" values; I'd make the relationship between the "g" checkboxes and the "h" fields more explicit, either by using "data-" attributes or else by grouping the elements in some regular way (inside a `<span>` with a particular class, or something else meaningful).  I don't like polluting the markup either, but there's usually a good balance to be found when what you're doing makes sense overall.

Comment: Short and sweet! Minor issue: You are missing the `#` in front of the `'h'`.

Comment: @veredsmarald yes I just noticed that - one of my laptops has a sticky "5" key, and now this one is developing a sticky "3" :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this one;

```
function shorter(selecter, selecter1) {
    if (!$(selecter + ':checked').length) {
        $("#" + selecter1).val("No");
    } else {
        $("#" + selecter1).val("Yes");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    ($("#g"+i+":checked").length) ? $("#h"+i).val("No") : $("#h"+i).val("Yes");
}
```

That being said, I would also adjust your markup a bit as the poster above suggested. Perhaps give them all a class to easily collect them, then maybe an arbitrary attribute to indicate their number/position like `<div class='checkbox' position='3'></div>` or something similar

Comment: A downvote? Really? This answered the question perfectly fine, at least explain why you don't like it :-/

Comment: I didn't downvote, but whoever did may have done so due to the lack of dynamicity in your solution.  If the OP went with this then, whenever elements were added or taken away the script would also have to be adjusted.  Interestingly, I just noticed my answer was also down voted despite being quite similar to the top voted answer here.

Comment: I'm not the down-voter, but `($("#g"+i+":checked").length) ? $("#h"+i).val("No") : $("#h"+i).val("Yes");` is a lot harder to look at than `$("#h"+i).val($("#g"+i)[0].checked ? "Yes" : "No");`. Also your solution is not flexible if the number of checkboxes changes later. Finally, the OPs code doesn't have a `g1` and `h1` they are just named `g` and `h`, but here I would completely support you in saying they should be renamed.